# ¿Cómo optimizar estos bloques condicionales?

Tags: php

Quisiera saber cómo optimizar el código, evitar tantos `if` anidados y demás:

```
<?php
if(!empty($u))
  {
    if(!empty($e))
    {
      if(!empty($c))
      {
        if(strlen($ul)>=4 and strlen($ul)<24)
        {
          if(strlen($el)>5 and strlen($el)<37)
          {
            if(strlen($c)>3 and strlen($c)<25)
            {
              if(strpos($el, '@') and strpos($el, '.'))
              {
                if(mysqli_num_rows($r)===0)
                {
                    $con->query("INSERT INTO sv_nicks (Contra, Email, Nick) VALUES ('$ce', '$el', '$ul')");
                    echo "<script>document.getElementById('error').style='color:#228B22';document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'Estos son tus datos:<br>Usuario: $ul.<br>Contraseña: $c.<br>E-mail: $el.'</script>";
                }else{echo "<script>document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'El usuario o el e-mail se encuentran en uso.'</script>";}
              }else{echo "<script>document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'El e-mail debe contener el arroba(@) y el punto(.) correspondiente.'</script>";}
            }else{echo "<script>document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'La contraseña debe tener entre 4 y 24 carácteres.'</script>";}
          }else{echo "<script>document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'El e-mail debe tener entre 6 y 36 carácteres.'</script>";}
        }else{echo "<script>document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'El usuario debe tener entre 4 y 24 carácteres.'</script>";}
      }else{echo "<script>document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'Debes ingresar una contraseña.'</script>";}
    }else{echo "<script>document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'Debes ingresar un e-mail.'</script>";}
  }else{echo "<script>document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'Debes ingresar un usuario.'</script>";}
```

Comment: ¿Optimizar para una mejor lectura? ¿Para minimizar las comprobaciones que se hacen en total? ¿Para recudir el número de `if`s? Para empezar me gustaría advertirte que tu código es vulnerable a [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyección_SQL) y [XSS](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting).

Comment: Para recudir el número de ifs. Para inyecciones he creado un filtro: $lp = array(" ", "-", "DROP", "TABLE", "ALTER", "SELECT", "INSERT", "VALUES", "FROM", "INTO", "CREATE", "SET", "SQL", "PDO", "$", "DELETE", "UPDATE", "'", "=", ";", "á", "é", "ó", "ú", "í", "ñ", "(", ")", "&", ":", "*", "=", "{", "}", "+", "Á", "É", "Í", "Ó", "Ú", "%", "?", "/", "Ñ", "LIKE", "<", ">", "[", "]", "?", "%", "#", "!", '"', "{", "}");
  $u=$_POST['usuarioingresado'];
  $ul=str_replace($lp, "", $u);

Comment: Con todos mis respetos, usar filtros es una solución insegura que podría ser saltada y, además, estás impidiendo hacer uso de muchos caracteres que podrían necesitarse. Debes usar consultas preparadas o bien la función de entrecomillado de mysqli. Mañana te redacto una respuesta reduciendo el número de `if` y dando formato al código siguiendo la recomendación PSR-2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes intentar una evaluación estructurada, algo parecido a otra pregunta que hiciste. Al final te mostraré una forma de hacerlo, no sin antes señalar algunas cosas que veo:

1. Hay algunos errores de lógica en tu programa. Por ejemplo, no deberías modificar el elemento del DOM cuyo id es `error` en los casos en que el resultado es exitoso. Por lógica, ese contenedor debería ser usado únicamente para los casos de error. Deberías quizá crear otro contenedor con id `success`. Si observas, la práctica actual obliga a hacer un cambio en el estilo de ese contenedor: `echo "<script>document.getElementById('error').style='color:#228B22';document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'Estos son tus datos:<br>Usuario: $ul.<br>Contraseña: $c.<br>E-mail: $el.'</script>";`, cambiándole el color, para habilitarlo a mostrar un contenido exitoso. Me dirás que así te ahorras un contenedor. Ok. Pero no es lógico y es menos performante, porque operas una modificación adicional sobre un elemento...
2. No comprendo bien por qué diferencias entre las variables `$u, e, $c` por un lado y luego `$ce,$el,$ul`. Usas unas para el `INSERT` y otras para indicar que *esos son tus datos*. Parece que hay una confusión entre esas variables que dificulta una solución simple del problema.
3. Como ya señaló @OscarGarcia, la inserción es vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL. Es muy fácil corregir eso, de hecho, lo he corregido usando consultas preparadas. En ese aspecto el código de la respuesta es segura, no recurras a filtros oscuros, inventados por ti mismo que además de complicados se revelan ineficaces de cara a la protección real contra inyección. Si usas `prepare` y `execute` tal cual no necesitas proteger nada más con respecto a la base de datos.
4. La lógica para indicar que el usuario ha sido insertado tampoco es correcta. Debes evaluar tanto el `execute` como el resultado de `affected_rows`. Es la única forma de saber si hubo una inserción real. En la respuesta se evalúa esa posibilidad, agregando a `$txtOutput` un mensaje de error en caso de que ocurra al momento de insertar. Hay que pensar en errores de clave duplicada por ejemplo y otro posibles errores.

El código va controlando y estructurando un array de datos al cual le agregará una clave `msg` con los mensajes de error que vayan ocurriendo.

Dado que la evaluación de aquí es un  poco más particular, el código maneja otra variable `$otherMsg` para ir concatenando otros tipos de mensajes de error sobre evaluaciones que no son ya sobre la nulidad de ciertas variables, sino sobre su tamaño, etc.

Debo decir que en vez de hacer esta validación del lado del servidor, lo más conveniente sería hacerla del lado del cliente, mediante Javascript / HTML. Hay herramientas muy simples en JS / HTML para validad un email o el contenido, tamaño de los inputs. Puedes pasar el estado de los mismos por esa validación, activando el botón `Enviar` únicamente cuando los campos pasen la validación. Así además descargas de trabajo al servidor.

Yo validaría del lado del cliente y en el servidor sólo comprobaría, por si acaso, si los elementos del POST no están vacíos.

De todos modos, te escribí una respuesta, por si no puedes hacerlo del lado del cliente como te sugiero.

Mi propuesta sería esta. Espero te sea de utilidad:

```
$arrDatos=array();
$arrDatos['u']   = ( !empty($u) )  ? array ('data'=>$u)  : array('msg'=>'Debes ingresar un usuario.');
$arrDatos['e']   = ( !empty($e) )  ? array ('data'=>$e)  : array('msg'=>'Debes ingresar un e-mail.');
$arrDatos['c']   = ( !empty($c) )  ? array ('data'=>$c)  : array('msg'=>'Debes ingresar una contraseña.');

$otherMsg="";
$otherMsg  .= ( !(strlen($ul)>=4 and strlen($ul)<24) )      ? "" : 'El usuario debe tener entre 4 y 24 carácteres.<br />';
$otherMsg  .= ( !(strlen($el)>5 and strlen($el)<37) )       ? "" : 'El e-mail debe tener entre 6 y 36 carácteres.<br />';
$otherMsg  .= ( !(strlen($c)>3 and strlen($c)<25) )         ? "" : 'El e-mail debe tener entre 6 y 36 carácteres.<br />';
$otherMsg  .= ( !(strpos($el, '@') and strpos($el, '.')) )  ? "" : 'El e-mail debe contener el arroba(@) y el punto(.) correspondiente.<br />';
$arrDatos['o']   = ( !$otherMsg )  ? array ('data'=>"")  : array('msg'=>'<br />Otros errores: <br />'.$otherMsg);

if(array_column($arrDatos, 'msg')) {
    $txtOutput=implode("<br />",array_column($arrDatos, 'msg'));
}else{
    /*
         *Aquí debería lanzarse la consulta que trae los datos de $r
         *No tiene sentido hacerla fuera sin saber si se usará o no
    */
    if($r->num_rows===0) {
        $sql="INSERT INTO sv_nicks (Contra, Email, Nick) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt=$con->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param("sss", $ce,$el,$ul);
        if ( $stmt->execute() && $con->affected_rows > 0 ) {
            echo "<script>document.getElementById('error').style='color:#228B22'</script>";
            $txtOutput="Estos son tus datos:<br>Usuario: $ul.<br>Contraseña: $c.<br>E-mail: $el";
        }else{
            $txtOutput="Error: $con->error";    
        }                                       
    } else {
        $txtOutput="El usuario o el e-mail se encuentran en uso";
    }
}
echo "<script>document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = '".$txtOutput."'</script>";
```

Quizá se pueda mejorar todavía, concatenando solamente mensajes de error en vez de guardar los datos en el array. Pero como dije antes, no entiendo por qué usas 6 variables distintas.

Comment: Las variables $u, $c y $e reciben datos post, las variables $u y $e se limpiaban con el filtro, y $ce es porque hashea la contraseña con whirlpool, y si hasheara inmediatamente, me fijo si $c es empty y va a dar que no porque empty en whirlpool, sí tiene valor.

Comment: Si reciben datos POST puedes aprovechar los ternarios para evaluar/recuperar cada dato del POST (algo parecido a mi respuesta a tu otra pregunta). Lo otro no lo entendí bien. Sospecho que aún se puede optimizar mucho, pero habría que conocer todo el contexto. En este caso ignoraba lo del POST, aunque lo sospechaba (por la otra pregunta).